# Sending multipart form to backend service with multiple rows of data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying out a bulk upload functionality where I can get user details like name, email, and profile pic (file) as fields. Upon submitting, they are sent directly to backend models and stored.

I was able to successfully send just one row of data by using Form Data object and appending all the fields including image file field. The issue comes when the uploaded data is more than 1 row. I'm not able to figure out how to send Form Data as array of objects to my backend.

I tried appending formdata to array. So something like

```
    //  Convert this 
    //  [
    //   { name: 'xyz', email: 'xyz@gmai.com', img_name: 'xyz' }, 
    //   { name: 'abc', email: 'abc@gmail.com', img_name: 'abc' }
    //  ]
    //
    //  to 
    //
    //  [
    //   { name: 'xyz', email: 'xyz@gmai.com', image: BinaryFile }, 
    //   { name: 'abc', email: 'abc@gmail.com', image: BinaryFile }
    //  ]
    const newDataToSend = []

    // append image file to appropriate row according to name
    if (imageFiles && imageFiles.length > 0) {
      dataToSend.forEach(row => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        Object.keys(row).forEach(column => {
          if (column === "img_name") {
            let fileObj;
            for (let i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
              const file = imageFiles.item(i);
              if (file && file.name.indexOf(row[column]) > -1) {
                fileObj = file;
              }
            }
            if (fileObj) {
              formData.append("photo", fileObj);
            }
          } else {
            formData.append(column, row[column]);
          }
        });
        newDataToSend.push(formData);
      });
    }
```

This does not work. Throws error code 415 and payload is empty as well.

Are there any other solutions I can try?

Answer (score 0):

could you please add the other codes you have written . possibly you may not have a submit button .

Answer (score 0):

You could do `JSON.stringify` on the array data like shown in the code snippet:

```
let formdata = new FormData();
let dataArr = [data1, data2, data3];
formdata.append('dataArr', JSON.stringify(dataArr));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my purposes as I need to send the object with the file. So say, if the data is [{ name: 'xyz', email: 'xyz@gmai.com', image: BinaryFile }, {name: 'abc', email: 'abc@gmail.com', image: BinaryFile}]. I need to send this as it is. The issue I will face with your approach is that I will have to transform the formData to array of objects form in the backend. I want to avoid that if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in the form of an array of objects, you probably want to do something like this.

```
const dataToSend = [
  { firstName: 'Robin', lastName: 'Hood'}, 
  { firstName: 'Kavita', lastName: 'Gurav'}, 
  { firstName: 'Albert', lastName: 'Einstein'}
];


/** sending the data by the name 'data' */ 
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', dataToSend);

fetch(<api endpoint>, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});
```

The backend now should be able to read the data submitted from `data`.

I tried this on my browser, the payload being sent is like below.

[image]

Comment: Can you also give an example of how I would attach a file to this form data for each object?

Comment: For attaching file I guess you need to send it as an ArrayBuffer